# Click of disabled li event calls top li click event in Jquery mobile listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile listview which has 5 to 6 li's. Each one is bound with onclick event. For few of them applied `ui-disabled` class as part of logic. If you click on disabled li, which calls onclick event of immediate top li. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

one way is by using the :not css selector

```
 $('li:not(.ui-disabled)').click(function(){

 });
```

Comment: We have already added specific method on click of each li while generating listview

Answer (score 0):

I have removed onclick attribute from 'li' as well as 'a'.
Still it did not work.

When I removed ui-disabled class, It started working.